# AND grepl operation in R

Tags: regex, r, grepl

Suppose I have the following character

```
c <- "1 NA NA 4 5 6 NA NA 9 10 NA NA 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 NA NA 23 NA NA NA NA"
```

How can I grepl it to test it contains 1 and 5 and 6? Without getting 15, 16, etc. as false positive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use word boundary `\\b` around `1,5,6`:

```
grepl("\\b[156]\\b", c)
# [1] TRUE
```

If you want to check if all of the `1,5,6` are contained in the string, you can vectorize `grepl` on the pattern position:

```
all(Vectorize(grepl)(paste("\\b", c(1,5,6), "\\b", sep = ""), c))
# [1] TRUE
```

When we remove `1` from the string:

```
c <- "NA NA 4 5 6 NA NA 9 10 NA NA 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 NA NA 23 NA NA NA NA"

grepl("\\b[156]\\b", c)   # this is or condition, will still give true
# [1] TRUE

all(Vectorize(grepl)(paste("\\b", c(1,5,6), "\\b", sep = ""), c))  # This gives FALSE since 
# pattern \\b1\\b is not there
# [1] FALSE
```

Comment: sorry to chase you again - what's the approach to add 2-digit numbers, like 15? Assume I'll want 1, 5, 6, 16

Comment: You can add it to the vector as c(1,5,6,16) in the paste function which will construct a pattern of \\b16\\b to match 16.

Comment: one last question: what's the correct approach to apply your all(Vectorize(grepl)(paste("\\b", c(1,5,6), "\\b", sep = ""), c)) function to a column of a data.frame? for instance, I want to find out whether or not each row is meeting that condition to subset those who meet

Comment: You can use `outer`. `colSums(!outer(paste("\\b", c(1,5,6), "\\b", sep = ""), col, Vectorize(grepl))) == 0` suppose `col = df$somecolumn` is the column you want to test.

Comment: I'll test your patientce once again. For each row I create a vector of non-NA items for each c. like in this example it'll be c(4, 5, 6, 9, 10, 13, 14, ...., 23). But I was thinking I would get all rows, that contain the same non-NA items + anything else outside the mask, but it seems I'm mistaken. How can I achieve that?

Comment: I don't think I get your idea. This seems to have diverged from the original question. You can ask a separate question with better explanation if you don't mind, as it is data frame related to some extent.